# mysql left join execute time to long

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have found some examples, but still can't make it fast.

**songs table:**

```
song_id
song_name
```

**votes table:**

```
vote_id
song_id
vote_ip
```

**favorites table:**

```
favorite_id
song_id
favorite_owner
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT * FROM songs as s 
LEFT JOIN votes as v ON v.song_id = s.song_id 
AND v.vote_ip='78.63.35.138' 
LEFT JOIN favorites as f ON f.song_id = s.song_id 
AND (f.favorite_owner='78.63.35.138' 
OR f.favorite_owner='1') WHERE s.song_id!='' 
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1
;
```

I got the results, but the query execution time is 12 sec.

Comment: show the CREATE TABLE statement for all your tables, and the result of EXPLAIN SELECT ... on your query

Comment: what indexes have you got on the tables? have you tried using MySQL's `explain` function to see what it's doing? how much data is being loaded? You need to tell us more about all of this before anyone will be able to answer the question.

Comment: first, you are left joining against three tables - depending on the database size this will take time for sure. Second, `s.song_id != ''` really?  how many songs without an ID you got?!

Comment: structure:
http://server.us.lt/checker/codein.php?id=1474718125
explain:
http://s14.postimage.org/3xztjk4kh/Untitled_2.png

Maybe me query not? Maybe are simpler way to do it? i want just fuse 3 tables by song_id